# pygame not properly sensing actual state of caps lock and num lock state

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry this is a bit long. I want to be sure I completely describe the very odd behaviour that I am seeing and what I have already tried.

I am writing a python pygame program that takes keyboard events. I am trying to take numerical inputs from the keypad as well as from the normal numbers on the keypad (along with other input). However the num lock key state reported by pygame is causing a problem since it is not consistent with the actual keyboard state of the lock key.

The basics of this is pretty straightforward, I have the event loop

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
```

and have no issue getting the KEYDOWN events and checking the modifiers to apply from the event.mod bitmap and it all works fine. However I have discovered something unexpected. To be sure that the user is intending to hit say a 4 key on the keypad and not the left arrow the program needs to check the state of the num lock modifier key (the event.mod flags that come along with the event.key in the KEYDOWN event). Again that is straightforward, but there is an unexpected issue with the lock keys (num lock and caps lock) that have state and stay on or off.

The problem is that when the program starts it does not honour the current system state of the num lock key (while investigating this I have discovered the same behaviour with the caps lock key as well). Regardless of whether the caps lock or the num lock keys are on (and the LED indicators lit), when the pygame program starts it indicates the keys are in the off state. I have confirmed this using both the event.mod state and reading it directly with **pygame.key.get_mods()**. I can see the LED state of the key and can tell whether it is on. Regardless of whether I start the game with the lock off or on, it always reports the mod as off. If the LED is lit when I start the game the game reports it as off and if I then hit the lock key (turning the LED off) the game will now start indicating the mod as set!

Complicating it even more, if you move out of the game window and then change the state of the lock key and then go back, pygame does not recognise that the state has changed and still send the same event.mod flags as before.

It seems that pygame does not actually track the system state of the lock keys but assumes they are off when the program starts and only senses changes to the keys if they are toggled when the game has the focus.

As mentioned, I have tried **pygame.key.get_mods()** but that reports the same inconsistent state as the event.mod flags. I have also tried **pygame.key.set_mods()** but that just changes the games view of the state and does not affect or provide a way to match the underlying system state of the lock keys (the LEDs do not change state nor does it affect what other applications believe the state to be, just what pygame thinks it is).

I have done a lot of searching around and have not found anything that mentions that pygame does not track the system state of the caps lock and num lock keys.

This makes it completely confusing for a user, they can see that the caps lock or num lock LED is lit (or not) and yet the game is behaving inconsistently with those states.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Did you find a way to resolve it?

This incorrect behaviour on startup can be reproduced very simply by running this with the caps lock key on and then again with the caps lock off:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
print(pygame.key.get_mods())
```

I get 0 printed when running it with either the the caps lock on or off, indicating it is not getting the correct lock state at program startup.

Comment: do you use loop with `pygame.event.get()` ? If you don't use it then pygame may have old information about keyboard - because it use events from system to recognize pressed keys and it keeps this information in some values and `.get_mods()` (similar to `get_keys()`)  may return values from internal variable, not current state in system.

Comment: BTW: in most systems when porgram's window is not active then system doesn't send events with keys/mouse information to this window - and this is why you may get wrong values when you leave window and click key.

Comment: on Linux all keys shows correctly - but only if I use `pygame.event.get()` (or `pygame.event.pump()`) all time (in every loop). Without `pygame.event.get()` (or `pygame.event.pump()`) in loop it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW: there is even information about it in doc for [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) - `"To keep pygame in sync with the system, you will need to call pygame.event.pump() to keep everything current."`

Comment: @furas thanks for the comments. Yes I am using a standard 
`for event in pygame.event.get():` loop structure, but it is even simpler than that. If you just start up pygame with caps or num lock on and immediately do a `pygame.key.get_mods()`, it will tell you that they are off.
In terms of events that happen when the window is not active, I do not expect it to get those events, but I do expect it to accurately reflect the true system state of stateful keys like num lock. Those should be being obtained from the system and NOT internally tracked.

Comment: @furas 
The comment in the docs about event.pump() is if you are not using an event loop that processes the event queue, but I am.
Again this is not the issue though since it actually starts up incorrect saying they are off even if the program is started with caps lock or num lock on.

Comment: if you don't show code then we can exepect everything - I assumed that you didn't use `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.pump()` - or you use it not regullary.

Comment: to get correct results you may have to use `.get_mods()` after `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.pump()` because `pygame.event.get()` may get current states from system. And `.get_mods()` may only get results which `pygame.event.get()` get from system.

Comment: @furas I am doing this in Windows. Are you sure that it does it properly on Linux? In Windows a simple program that just does `pygame.init()` then `print(f"{pygame.key.get_mods()}")`
will say the mod is 0 regarless of whether the cap lock key is lit or not before it is run.

Comment: I tested it now and I get wrong result only if I run `get_mods()` before `set_mode()`. But if I run it after `set_mode()` then it gives correct value. And it seems correct because system sends events only to active window and `set_mode()` creates window. BTW: it show again how important is code in question. BTW: you can display it using `print(pygame.key.get_mods())`

Comment: BTW: if you want to get keys without displaying active window then maybe you should use [pynput.keyboard](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html)

Comment: I'm not trying to get events when out of the window, I just expect pygame to properly track the state of lock keys which are system things that can be changed out of the scope of the window.  Again more importantly, they start up wrong from the very beginning if the lock key is on when the program starts. In fact I only discovered this out of window behaviour after noticing they were wrong at startup. .

Comment: you have to run it after `set_mode()` which creates window and system starts to send events to program. I'm not sure but maybe all GUIs works this way.

Comment: I have tried `set_mods()` but that is not really useful, since I have no way of determining the actual state at startup. The program start believing that they are not set whether or not they are. You are right that I can then set them on with `set_mods()`, but I would have to somehow be able to programatically determine what the state of the lock keys within the code to be able to set them, which is the problem. There seems to be no way to actually find out what the external system state of the keys is.

Comment: i don't understand why you can't use it after `set_mode()` ? In most programs `set_mode()` is second command in code and everything runs after `set_mode()`

Comment: Just realized you said `set_mode()` not `set_mods()`. My real program does do that on startup, I just left it out of the 3 line test because it did not seem relevant.
I just tried adding it to the 3 liner right after the init, but it does not fix the issue. It still says that they are always off on startup.

Comment: yes I means `pygame.display.set_mode( (width, height), ... )` which creates window.

Comment: The program does do a `set_mode( ...)` command to create the window. Having that (or not having it) is not the problem.

Comment: Sorry to others that come here and have to wade through these comments. The exchange between probably should have been moved to a chat session, thought it did clarify that I was already doing the things he was asking about and I went back and edited the question to clarify those things. Thanks very much to @furas for the effort to assist me.  No resolution to the problem thouogh.

Answer (score -2):

Glenn. I might be wrong here, but this error just might be because of your computer version. Just saying.

Anyways, if it's **not** that, then we might have come across a bump on the road.

Your line of code could probably be affecting your program in a way. It's not a typo, that's for sure, so I'm thinking it's syntax error. You should be fine, so try to tinker in some ways that can get rid of it. Try not to click ignore, or it'll keep comin' back.

Good luck!